# Why is my go function parameter having a different size before calling the function and inside the function?

Tags: go

As part of a test to give Golang a go, I ended up hitting a roadblock, so I am a newbie.

I have written a quick toy program to search for a pattern in a list of strings, and I wanted to do it concurrently.

I have written a `search(data *[]string, input_string *string, channel chan<- []string)` function, taking a channel to send back the filtered `data` as a result.

However, `data` seems to have a different size before I pass it to the function, and inside the function: inside `search`, its size is very small, and just incorrect.

The full code is there: https://gitlab.com/jiehong/kata_test_language/-/blob/master/wiki.go#L39, so you can test it.

Basically, I fire up a list of go routines, and retrieve their results from their own channels one after the other:

```
var channels [](chan []string)
for _, chunk := range chunks {
    channel := make(chan []string, 1)
    channels = append(channels, channel)

    go search(&chunk, &input_string, channel)
}
var filtered_data []string
for _, channel := range channels {
    part_filtered := <-channel
    filtered_data = append(filtered_data, part_filtered...)
}
```

But `chunk`, although valid inside the loop, seems empty when `search` is handling it.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your example here is not complete enough to say for sure, but you probably need to read [Closures and Goroutines](https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines) from the [FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq)

Comment: See also [Common Mistakes: using go routines on loop iterator variables](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-goroutines-on-loop-iterator-variables).

Comment: What do you mean by the "size" of it? Where and how are you checking the variable size?

Comment: Also: Do not do `*[]string` passing a pointer  so a slice is wrong in all cases where the function doesn't need to modify the slice itself (and even in this case returning) the slice would be better).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `search` takes a `*[]string`. Changing it to `[]string` fixes it.

This was indicated by Volker as an "also", but is the fix.

This might be linked to https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-goroutines-on-loop-iterator-variables, as pointed by hmm.

Running `go vet wiki.go` did not warn about this issue though.